# Fluctuating brightness in RGB-LED strand controlled by Arduino

Tags: arduino, pwm, led-strip, rgb

I am controlling the three colors of an RGB strand using PWM output from an Arduino UNO (via IRF520N MOSFETs). When the signal to the LEDs is in midrange, the strand starts to visibly pulsate at a rate of about 10Hz or less. When the colors are on full load, the pulsating disappears. Eliminating one color at a time also mitigates or eliminates the pulsating.

After considering other options (the power supply is steady as a rock and designed for LED strands, for example), my working theory is that the brightness of the combined LEDs exhibits a "beat" effects as it is known in acoustics: when two notes of similar frequency are struck together, the ear can hear an audible fluctuation in volume. I was able to simulate a similar effect with rectangle waves mathematically:

[image: Beat effect in rectangle waves]

**Question:** Is this a reasonable theory, and -- other than limiting myself to seven colors -- how can this effect be mitigated to the extend of not being annoying anymore? If I want to use the LED strip as mood lighting, this sure is going to ruin it...

Comment: Probably all your PWM channels run from the same clock, so they can't beat with each other. Plus you wouldn't see it by eye even if they were at different frequencies.

Comment: The beat frequency is the difference in the frequency between the two PWM clocks, in this case you estimated that one must be 10 Hz faster than the other. However, if you only have one microcontroller with a single clock, then the beat frequency would be f1-f1=0 Hz and the beat would be at DC, not 10 Hz.  Also, you won't be able to see the beat frequency by eye for a lot of complicated reasons about how interference patterns are generated.

Comment: And yet I observe the beat pattern, so the only other explanation would be the switching in the transistors.

Comment: Probe the power to your transistor and microcontroller with an oscilloscope.  I'd also check Vgs as well when you see the flickering.  You may not be adequately decoupled somewhere.

Comment: You've suggested that the supply is steady. As a check that pulsating is *not* caused by PWM beating against a line frequency harmonic , alter PWM **period** slightly and see if beat frequency changes.

Comment: Glen: The online sources suggest that messing with the PWM period on the Arduino makes it behave unpredictably, so I'd rather not do that. However, I did use several capacitors (including none) between line and ground (to provide a shortcut for AC to ground) and it does not alter the behavior of the light. What does alter the behavior is the elimination of one or two colors, any one or any two. It makes the effect virtually or completely disappear. If it was the power supply, I'd expect a residual effect in any of these combinations, no?

Comment: 1850479: I don't have an oscilloscope handy, but I suspect checking whether the drain-to-source signal is still rectangular may be the only option left before putting in a digital-to-analog converter and using the transistor as variable resistor. I already swapped out the transistors for different once (IRF510N and IRF530N) and the effect remains: pulsating only at the middle of the brightness range and definitely only with more than one color active.

Comment: This is going to be very hard to troubleshoot with a scope since it'll have to be all trial and error to see what has an effect. Probably a good idea to show a diagram of your circuit, measure average currents, post a picture of the device you made, etc in case something jumps out as a problem.

Comment: Try to invert a pwm channel with a hex inverter ic, a couple of optos, or old-school BJTs, etc.

Comment: dandavis: The old-school BJTs was my first draft, but the transistors were only rated to 600mA (2N2222), so I ran the light strand with additional resistors...which mitigated brightness, but probably also the pulsating. 

The only opto-couplers I have right now are rated at 60mA. Do you know of any that are beefier?

I do not notice the pulsing looking at the strand directly -- I notice it looking at the indirect light reflected from the wall. It is quite slight. Maybe it's all in my brain...

Comment: MiNiMe: The Board Info says BN: Unknown Board; VID 0x1A86; PID: 0x7523; SN: (null). I noticed it starts to get unhappy if the load (as measured in DC) gets down to about 500mA. Above 1.5A, things smoothen out nicely. Is a low load an issue for a 5A power supply? If so, can I "fake" load for it? The voltage is 12V steady no matter the dim level.

Comment: I deleted my comment and wrote an answer instead. If it turns out you have the r4 Uno, then the part about the FET is still valid.

Comment: invert the pwm, not the drive itself. the signal is minisculeish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer I will assume you have an Uno up to rev 3.

For a start, the FET is not a logic level one. An Arduino Uno runs at 5 V, the IRF520N need more to fully switch on. Example of a better choice is IRLB8721.

About PWM frequency, this is what it looks like:

PWM Pins
3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11

PWM Frequency
490 Hz (pins 5 and 6: 980 Hz)

Source: [Arduino Reference](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogwrite/)

Hz is not very high for PWM, but at least there's two variants here for you to experiment with.

Comment: Thanks for the hardware tip! I noticed that there is a breakout board for the Arduino using the 520, and I could not find any alternative in all the Arduino/LED articles I found. I knew the 520 needs 9V, but I thought you need the 9V only if you want to run the full 9A. However, my trouble starts at the lower end of about 500mA and goes away as I start to hit 2A. Definitely going to try your recommendation, though!

Comment: With the IRF520N the RDS(on) is much higher when gate is driven with 3.3 V and you want more punch for the load, not for the heatsink of the FET. || But I say the PWM frequency could be better for your application. It can be done with the Arduino though, search for arduino pwm frequency increase.

Comment: So, ahm, yes - I experienced some trepidation about mucking about at that low a level, but apparently that did, indeed, the trick. The strand, with all color combos, now dims without pulsating from "off" to "too bright to stare into for long."

That was not bleeding obvious, so much the greater is my gratitude for sending me on that route. Someone else in the comments above also mentioned it as a thing to try, so thank you as well, but at the time I was still too timid to try it.